# installer command not found in linux system

Tags: linux, sudo

I created a java application where i run some linux commands with sudo privilege so to set password for my system i use this code

```
     String[] cmd = {"/bin/bash","-c","echo "+pw+"| sudo -S installer -pkg /"+userHomePath+" -target"};
         
        
         
         Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

            // Read the output

            BufferedReader reader =  
                  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null && !line.equals("[?1034h")) {
               // System.out.print("output"+line + "\n");
            }
            
            proc.waitFor();   
            }
```

it runs with no issues in my system but when i run in my client system it says

```
[sudo] password for yue.chen: sudo: installer: command not found
```

what could be the reason someone share your views .

Comment: Could it be that `installer` is, in fact, not present? Or is that too obvious?

Comment: what is mean by installer thats my question .Sorry i'm not aware of linux

Comment: Don't know -- I don't have an `installer` executable on my Linux system. `installer -pkg` is something I've seen on Mac OS/X. It's possible that some Linux distributions have a utility called "installer", but I don't know what they are.

Comment: actually client system is a redhat OS system . So any chances for it

Comment: Neither RHEL nor Fedora have a standard utility called `installer`. It might have been provided by some other piece of software.

Comment: oh fyn what is your recommendation to overcome the error

Comment: I'm sorry -- I have nothing to suggest. This isn't a question about programming, but about system set-up.